# Windows 10 in a domain takes forever to login

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

I have multiple computers using the same account in a domain.
When the users try to log in, the process take very long time (10/15 minutes).
I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mixed DNS system (your DNS servers having both internal and external DNSs) this is exactly what can happen.

To fix it, on the servers side:

- remove external DNSs from IP configuration of your domain's DNS servers
- Flush your DNS
- Net Stop DNS
- Net Start DNS
- Net Stop Netlogon
- Net Start Netlogon
- Re-register DNS (ipconfig /registerdns)

on the client side:

- restart workstations and re-login them

Answer (score 0):

Also check your logon-scripts, if you have mappings to servers that are no longer reachable it adds quite a delay.